# Classifying counts of repeat visits per user for a website

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, database, statistics

I am trying to get number of times (or sessions) a user re-visited the website.

What I'm trying to find out-

Get the total number of users, number of sessions in the last 30days. I need to a pie chart ultimately where it shows people who revisited-

1. more than 100 times,
2. 50-100 times,
3. less than 50 times

The problem with the current implementation I see is -

The whole set of data(like 100million rows) are being computed every time(for each query with different condition)

```
SELECT COUNT(A.sess) as acount, SUM(A.sess) as asum, AVG(A.sess) as aavg
FROM
(SELECT ipaddress,
        COUNT(*) AS sess
   FROM analytics
   WHERE trunc(datecreated) > getdate() - interval '30 days'
   GROUP BY trunc(datecreated), ipaddress
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 100) AS A

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(B.sess) as bcount, SUM(B.sess) as bsum, AVG(B.sess) as bavg
FROM
(SELECT ipaddress,
        COUNT(*) AS sess
   FROM analytics
   WHERE trunc(datecreated) > getdate() - interval '30 days'
   GROUP BY trunc(datecreated), ipaddress
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 100 AND COUNT(*) >=50 ) AS B

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(C.sess) as ccount, SUM(C.sess) as csum, AVG(C.sess) as cavg
FROM
(SELECT ipaddress,
        COUNT(*) AS sess
   FROM analytics
   WHERE trunc(datecreated) > getdate() - interval '30 days'
   GROUP BY trunc(datecreated), ipaddress
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 50 ) AS C
```

How do I optimize the query?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL version 8 supports [common table expression](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/).  If you want to differentiate between the three sub queries, use a column containing literal:

```
WITH SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH AS (
SELECT ipaddress,
        COUNT(*) AS sess
   FROM analytics
   WHERE trunc(datecreated) > getdate() - interval '30 days'
   GROUP BY trunc(datecreated), ipaddress
)
SELECT 'MORE THAN 100' AS CATEGORY, 
       COUNT(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as acount, 
       SUM(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as asum, 
       AVG(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as aavg
FROM SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH
WHERE sess >= 100

UNION ALL

SELECT 'BETWEEN 50 AND 100' AS CATEGORY, 
       COUNT(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as bcount, 
       SUM(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as bsum, 
       AVG(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as bavg
FROM SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH
WHERE sess < 100 AND sess >=50

UNION ALL

SELECT 'LESS THAN 50' AS CATEGORY, 
       COUNT(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as ccount, 
       SUM(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as csum, 
       AVG(SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH.sess) as cavg
FROM SESSIONS_THIS_MONTH
WHERE sess < 50
```